# How can i get cart item img src woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Via this code i get full block this img, but i want only src.

```
<?php
            global $woocommerce;
            $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

            foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
                $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());
                echo "<li><a href=\"#0\"><img src=\"".**SRC HERE**."\" class=\"img-responsive\"></a></li>";
            } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this

```
wp_get_attachment_url($getProductDetail->get_image_id());
```

so your code becomes:

```
$getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );
$url = wp_get_attachment_url($getProductDetail->get_image_id());
echo "<li><a href='#0'><div class='cart-mini-img'><img src='".$url."' class='img-responsive'></div></a>";
```

Comment: Nothing display in src